# ¿Cómo puedo sumar numeros con un arreglo de tipo Object?

Tags: java

No se cómo se suma en este tipo de arreglo, y he intentado mucho pero no he podido lograr sumarlos

```
Object [ ] obj = new Object[1];

obj [0] = 1;
obj [1] = 2;
```

Comment: No puedes sumar Object por que si. Lo que puedes hacer es si son numericos convertirlos a su tipo numerico y alli ya sumar. Aparte, si todo van a ser de un tipo no tiene sentido usar Object

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Ele, es importante agregar lo que hayas tratado o investigado,  revisa [ask] que te brinda información para crear preguntas, te invitamos también a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente es importante dimensionar correctamente tu array de objetos, si deseas agregar 2 elementos, debes definir de esta forma:

```
Object[ ] obj = new Object[2];//Contendrá 2 elementos.
obj [0] = 1;
obj [1] = 2;
```

Ahora para poder sumar estos valores debes convertirlos a un tipo numérico en este caso `int`, puedes realizar un casting, ejemplo:

```
 int valor1 = (int)obj[0];
 int valor2 = (int)obj[1];
```

Con la información anterior puedes ahora realizar la suma de los elementos almacenados en el `array` de objetos:

```
    Object[] obj = new Object[2];
    obj[0] = 1;
    obj[1] = 2;

   //Variable donde se almacenará la suma.
    int resultado = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<obj.length;i++){
       //Convierte entero el valor almacenado en el objeto y lo suma.
        resultado += (int)obj[i]; 
    }

    System.out.println("Resultado suma: " + resultado);
```

---

**[Demo online.](https://ideone.com/UuU3gd)**

Answer (score 0):

La forma más adecuada de declarar arreglos con dimensión estática es la siguiente:

```
Tipo_de_variable[ ] Nombre_del_array = new Tipo_de_variable[dimensión];
```

En tu caso sería: `int obj = new int[1]` y la asignación se hace como lo estás haciendo.

> **Consejo:** Java es un lenguaje fuertemente tipado, por tanto al realizar códigos de este estilo estás desaprovechando la potencia del
>   lenguaje pues la clase Object es una superclase de todas las clases
>   del lenguaje Java, es decir, estás haciendo un arreglo genérico.